# Question closed too soon? #36524 bridge-two-subnets-together

Tags: discussion

I think [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36524/bridge-two-subnets-together) was closed too soon.  The subject is certainly within the realm of this site.  There are many solutions to the OP's problem -- some would entail adding network devices, and some might be reconfiguring hosts. I think until either the OP says adding devices is not possible, or explicitly asks for help configuring his hosts, it should remain open.

Comment: I reopened it. The question does say, "_All routing is done through unmanaged switches and hubs._"  In the comments, "_there are no extra NICs and it is not feasible to install a new PCI network interface card in these machines._"